# How to prove that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and any $p>0$, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-p} > \int_{1}^{n+1}x^{-p}dx > \sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k^{-p}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Here is a question for my Math homework,

Prove that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and any $p>0$, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-p} > \int_{1}^{n+1}x^{-p}dx > \sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k^{-p}$

I want to use methods learned from Sequence and Series and limits to prove this.

Comment: elcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{k}^{k+1}(k+1)^{-p}dx<\int_{1}^{n+1}x^{-p}dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{k}^{k+1}x^{-p}dx<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{k}^{k+1}k^{-p}dx,$$
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{n+1}k^{-p}< \int_{1}^{n+1}x^{-p}dx <\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-p}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Just split the integral into integrals over $(j,j+1)$ and note that $(j+1)^{-p}<x^{-p} <j^{-p}$ on $(j,j+1)$.